# OkHttp is trying to connect to a different baseurl then configured in retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I am getting following logs with `HttpLoggingInterceptor` added to `Retrofit`

```
OkHttp: --> GET http://192.168.1.13/api/config
D/OkHttp: --> END GET
```

and then

```
D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP FAILED: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /192.168.1.20:8888
D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP FAILED: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
```

Note the difference in base url and url in connect exception. I am not sure what is causing this. In my application server URL is not known at compile time, so retrofit adapter is created at runtime. Here is relevant code

```
    private void init() {
    mBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    // TODO: 08/04/16 might want to remove this in prod
    mBuilder.hostnameVerifier((s, sslSession) -> true);

    mBuilder.connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    mBuilder.readTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    mBuilder.writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    // Add headers
    mBuilder.interceptors().add(chain -> {
        Request request = chain.request();

        request = request.newBuilder()
                .build();
        return chain.proceed(request);
    });

    // Logging
    if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        mBuilder.interceptors().add(interceptor);
    }

    mGson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
            .setDateFormat(Constants.DATE_FORMAT)
            .create();

    sDispatcher = new Dispatcher();
    sDispatcher.setMaxRequests(10);
    mBuilder.dispatcher(sDispatcher);
}

public void setIpAddress(String ipAddress){
    init();
    String newBaseUrl = "http://"+ ipAddress;
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = mBuilder.build();
    mRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(newBaseUrl)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(mGson))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io()))
            .build();

    mService = mRetrofit.create(APIService.class);
}
```

Everytime I need to change base url I just call `setIpAddress` method,

Answer (score 0):

I had a proxy setup for this particular wifi connection few days back. That is why logs were printing connection to a different ip address and api calls were failing because that proxy was down.